# MenuFlyout always focus second item of it When down Key is Pressed in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the following code:

```
Button b=new Button();
Button.Content="Button";
Button.Click+=Click;
MenuFlyout MenuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
MenuFlyoutItem MenuFlyoutItem1 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
MenuFlyoutItem MenuFlyoutItem2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
MenuFlyoutItem MenuFlyoutItem3 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
MenuFlyoutItem1.Text="Prem";
MenuFlyoutItem2.Text="Kumar";
MenuFlyoutItem3.Text="Deepak";
MenuFlyout.Items.Add(MenuFlyoutItem1);
MenuFlyout.Items.Add(MenuFlyoutItem2);
MenuFlyout.Items.Add(MenuFlyoutItem3);


private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Button.ContextFlyout = menuFlyout;
      menuFlyout.ShowAt(Button, new Point(-20, 20));   
}
```

`MenuFlyout` opens perfectly, but when `MenuFlyout` is opened, if I press Down Key it always focuses the second `MenuFlyoutItem`. I Don't know why it does not focus the first `MenuFlyoutItem`. I Want it to focus first `MenuFlyoutItem` when down key is pressed and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, when you click, the first menu item is focused, although it is not visible visually. You can confirm that by clicking the button and then pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The fact the item is not visually highlighted is you clicked with a mouse, so the control assumes you will continue your interaction with a mouse, which has hover effects instead.

[image: Starting click by mouse]

If you, instead, click the button by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the first place, it will now actually show you the highlight rectangle around the first menu item to indicate it is focused, as you have started the interaction with the keyboard.

[image: Keyboard click]

This behavior is consistent with the rest of the system, so it is best to keep it as users may depend on it.

As an additional tip, you don't have to attach the flyout during the click event, but you can just set `Button.Flyout` beforehand and just remove the `Click` handler:

```
b.Flyout = MenuFlyout;
```

`ContextFlyout` is in general used for right-click event. To ensure the flyout opens below the control, you can set its `Placement` property:

```
MenuFlyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
```

Comment: is there any way to focus first menuflyoutitem when clicking?

Comment: As I mentioned it is focused, although not visually. If you really want this, you can try focus it by calling: `MenuFlyoutItem1.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);`